# Who comes 2nd, texas hold em

Tags: rules

This happened last night to us. 
Player A has 2500 chips and goes all in pre flop.
Player B has 2100 chips and goes all in.
Player C has 8000 chips and calls.

Player A has a pair of 9's.
Player B has a pair of aces.
Player C has a flush.

Player C wins the pot but who comes 2nd?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: There is no 2nd.  Player C has them covered.

Comment: I think he means it’s a tournament and they need to know who to give second prize to, in which case its player A because they had more chips than player B at the start of the hand.

Answer (score 2):

If multiple players bust in a tournament in the same hand they are ranked in respect to their chipstacks. The bigger the stack the higher the rank.

In this case player A will get second place and player B will get third place.